# Batch and batch-file tags

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request, tag-cleanup-request

There are [batch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch) and [batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) tags. Their description is pretty much the same:

[batch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch)

> the execution of a set of commands or software programs without user intervention. A batch file is a text file

---

[batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file)

> Text file containing a sequence of commands or program invocations that does not need user intervention.

Should they be made synonyms of each other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[batch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch) (1325 Qs) currently refers to batch operations in OSes other than Windows, which has a very specific type of [batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file)s (678 Qs). IMO [batch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch) should be renamed to [batch-operation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-operation) to avoid confusion with .bat files and its scripting language.

Comment: I see what you mean and I like your idea.

Comment: How do you think - should I edit my post to reflect this finding? Should I change tag from `tag-synonym-request` to something else?

Comment: It's your post. You can change it however you like.

Comment: `batch-operation` is not a helpful tag. When users refer to batch files in the Windows environment, they should be tagged `cmd.exe` (which will be renamed at some point as well). All other uses of "batch" are usually irrelevant and should be removed.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg batch scripts aren't necessarily tied to `cmd`. The batch scripting language is in fact a little different for typing commands directly into command line and executing them from a `.bat` file. I just pointed out that there should be another solution to this tag confusion.

Comment: @user1306322 No, there shouldn't be another solution. We don't need a tag for everything just because it differs from an existing topic in some minute detail.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I believe a whole scripting language should not be considered a "minute detail". At the very least, you can use `cmd.exe` tag for questions about things other than the batch scripts. Which kinda warrants a separation of the topics. It's like only using `Visual-Studio` tag even though it works with multiple programming languages and is also a tool for viewing library contents and resource files.

Comment: @user1306322 My point is, it doesn't matter if the question is about a batch file or generally processing of batches. What is relevant is what interpreter is being used.

Comment: A quick look at the questions with these tags shows that this description of the tags' usage is spurious. This is not how the tags are being used, and the tag wikis do not indicate this usage either. I see these as two piles of the same stuff that needs to be merged and then cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the questions with these tags, I can't discern a difference in their application to merit having two tags. Despite what is claimed above, there is no apparent correlation of one tag to Windows and the other to other operating systems. The tag wikis are essentially the same, so it would be shocking if users were somehow divining that they should apply the tags in a way that depended on the OS in use.

The questions in each tag are the same hodgepodge of scripting topics. I suggest first synonymizing these tags, merging the content into [batch-file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/batch-file).

Once merged, there should be a cleanup of this tag. Generic batch operation questions that are not about writing/using/manipulating a batch file (`.bat`) should be retagged to reflect the scripting language or interpreter being used.